# How to enable spring support in IntelliJ Community Edition 2016.1.3

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I have very good pure Java basic knowledge. As long as there are no XML config and no project management tools involved, I am very good.

The things that really confused me are the project management tools, e.g.: Maven, Gradle.

I am learning Spring, and it is so confusing to me since it involves many XML files and there is no clear explanation for it.

I am learning Spring from [this set](https://www.udemy.com/javaspring/) of video tutorials, Lecture 6
Spring "Hello World".

I couldn't get a Spring hello world done because it requires a xxxxx.xml file to config the beans (Java object). To generate the XML files, I need to generate an XML file using a plugin on IntelliJ 2016.

The question is I can't find the plugin to generate a XML file for the bean by following [this official tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/enabling-spring-support.html). There is no such plugin called " Spring Support".

What should I do to generate the beans.xml? (The file to manage beans for Spring)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's take things one by one:

1. Your problem understanding builds management tools like maven and gradle. Try these links for tutorials: [Maven in 5 Minutes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html), gradle is very advance build automation tool with continuous Integration features, you can find a good comparison between gradle and maven [here](http://gradle.org/maven_vs_gradle/).
2. If you are confused about spring to try this book: Spring in Action 3rd Edition (4th Edition is also available, I recommend 3rd edition as you will be able to link XML to annotations.)
3. You do not need any tool to generate XML files. Copy a sample spring configuration file from the internet, remove unwanted elements and write your own beans.

Answer (score 28):

You can't enable Spring support with IntelliJ community Edition, it only available with paying version (Ultimate).
However, you can create the .xml file manually and CE version also supports it (a little bit).
To working with Spring or J2EE, you should get familiar with build tools like Maven, Gradle (or Ant in some special case). The concept is simple and you can get it easily from the official website (https://maven.apache.org/ - http://gradle.org/).
For Spring, if you are not familiar with creating a .xml file, you can use Java configuration instead or move to use Spring-boot to forget this configuration file (almost).
However, at first, I think you should get the basic concept of Spring and try to work well with .xml files configure. It'll be helpful in the future when you work with it deeply.

Comment: +1: No free Java EE coding with JetBrains. $50 a month. You could use the Pivotal Spring Tools 4 plugin for Eclipse at  https://spring.io/tools

Comment: @Trunk: IntelliJ costs $15/mo for the individual license and gets cheaper over time if you take the annual billing - down to $7.50/mo in the 3rd year.

Comment: @nkr: My apologies - mixed up monthly price with €500 a year tab. Yes - €300 a year after 2 years. Not a lot for pro coders. But too much for starters.

Comment: @Trunk that for organisation.. an individual license is only 150$ us.. after 2 years its 89$ us. I think for starters its more reasonable but i got confused too.. they should make it more clearer. However, i do find Eclipse or STS more suited for the task.. and i actually have no problems using it. Probably best for starters..

Comment: @Rushino: Yes. But maybe the $150 easier to keep than make ! Seriously, it's good value at that even for starters. Especially if they let them pay monthly.

Comment: @Trunk So if i understand correct.. Spring or Spring boot aren't supported in the sense that it won't build the project for you. But you can import a Spring or Spring boot project in it and get the same base features such (intellisense, code completion, smart stuff, etc.)?

Comment: @Rushino: Honestly, I don't know. I doubt if you can import (meaningfully or usefully) a Spring project started in Eclipse or wherever. If you did, you hardly get much advantage in having Intellisense and no built-in Spring tools.

Answer (score 9):

The Spring support plugin is a feature of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, which is a commercial IDE. It's not available in the free Community Edition.

You don't need any plugin to generate the beans.xml file; you can write it manually in the source code editor.

Answer (score 8):

For Spring support, did you try "Spring Assistant" plugin ?

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10229-spring-assistant

Good part it is it has active development.

**Edit on Aug 21, 2020:**
Seems like this plugin has no more active development.  Its last release was in 2018 April.

No need to worry.  We sill have some good news :-)

Its Github repository is [here](https://github.com/1tontech/intellij-spring-assistant).  We can clone the repo and make necessary changes what ever we specifically need.

Comment: Unfortunately, the plugin that served part of the idea/spring community, stopped maintaining. I took the liberty of creating a fork, we fixed bugs and added new features.
the same can be found directly in the search for Intellij or in the marketplace.
[Spring Initializr and Assistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18622-spring-initializr-and-assistant)

Answer (score 1):

I know you are asking about IntelliJ Idea but as it is a commercial tool, you should pay to let you use its plugins. Another way is using "Spring Tools for Eclipse" which is a great environment to develop Spring applications. But you need to be familiar with eclipse.
It can be downloaded from:
[Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse](https://spring.io/tools)

Comment: I find Spring Tools for Eclipse easier than Intelliji to use. It work and you get results fast. Intelliji look like you need some time to get used to it. Not saying Intelliji is less good btw. Probably in the long run, it do help a lots.