# Why can't I choose Spring Initializr in IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: java-me

I just downloaded the latest IntelliJ **`IDE`**, but I can not find the Spring Initializr, look at the Screenshot.

How can I deal with it, or can I only use Eclipse？ By the way, I have installed the plugins "Spring Boot", but it works less.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Theres plenty of answers to this question if you look around. A simple "Google" search is all you need.

[How to enable spring support in IntelliJ Community Edition 2016.1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019094/how-to-enable-spring-support-in-intellij-community-edition-2016-1-3)

You have not indicated if you are using the CE version or a licensed version. I have to assume you are using a license version here as CE version *does not have* any support for *Spring* plugins.

As you say if you have enabled *Spring Boot* plugin under *IntelliJ > Plugins* then make sure the checkbox is ticked to enable it. A mistake alot of people make.