IDEA project configuration issues
this happened on my IDEA -community.
as the picture sign,I down load the plugin from intellij-idea's official website,so i add it to my IDEA from local,then error said.
I'm fresh learner of java.
how to solve this problem？in another word,how to download spring on IDEA -community?

You can have a Maven dependency for Spring Boot application.

Spring plugin is available for Ultimate version only, you can see that when you search the plugin from Settings | Plugins | Marketplace

Are there any plug-ins in the market that enable me to use Spring services in the community version?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38027421/22911640
